# Gatsby with Laravel Sanctum 401 Unauthorized

Tags: laravel, authentication, gatsby

I am geting a ***401 Unauthorized*** response.

I followed [Laravel Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#spa-authenticating) docs

I'm currently working on localhost for both frontend and backend:

frontend (Gatsby version 2.31): localhost:8001 <- used "*npm start*"
backend (Laravel version 8.26.1): localhost:8000 <- used "*php artisan serve*"

Here's what I have setup:

Gatsby: ***signup.js***:

```
import apiClient from "../utils/api";

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  apiClient().get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then( () => {   

     apiClient().post("/api/register", {
         firstName: "newfirst",
         lastName: "newlast",
         email: "email@domain.com",
         password: "123456"
     }
     ).then(function (response) {
         if (response.data.error) {
           console.log("Error: ",response.data.error);
         } else {
           console.log("Success");
         }        
     })
     .catch(function (error) {
       console.log(error);
     });
  });
}
```

Gatsby: ***util/api.js:***

```
import axios from "axios";

export default function api() {
  const apiClient = axios.create({
     baseURL: "http://localhost:8000",
     withCredentials: true
  });
  return apiClient;
}
```

Laravel 8:
Installed Sanctum by following [Laravel Sanctum installation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#installation)

***.env***

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:8001 // <- from what I understand, this should point to the frontend
```

***config/cors.php***

```
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],
'supports_credentials' => true,
```

***app/Http/Kernel.php***

```
use Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful;

protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [...],
    'api' => [
        EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        'throttle:api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];
```

***config/sanctum.php***

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env(
    'SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', 
    'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:800,::1,localhost:8000'
)),
```

no changes in *config/sanctum.php* as SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS can be entered in *.env* file

***routes/api.php***

```
Route::post("register", [AuthController::class, "register"])->middleware("auth:sanctum");
```

***app/Http/Controllers/AuthControllers.php***

```
public function register(Request $request) {

    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
    $user = $this->create($request->all());
    return response()->json([
        'user' => $user,
        'message' => 'registration successful'
    ], 200);

}
```

***config/auth.php***

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'sanctum', //<- I also updated this from "token" to "sanctum"
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

Solutions I tried:

adding "header" to api call in *Gatsy > signup.js*:

```
apiClient().get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then( () => {   

  const token = Cookies.get("XSRF-TOKEN"); //<- npm install js-cookie
  
  apiClient().post("/api/register", {
      firstName: "newfirst",
      lastName: "newlast",
      email: "email@domain.com",
      password: "123456"
    }, {
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer "+ token //<- added this part
      }
    }
  ).then(function (response) {
```

also this in "header"

```
apiClient().get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then( () => {   

  const token = Cookies.get("XSRF-TOKEN");
  
  apiClient().post("/api/register", {
      firstName: "newfirst",
      lastName: "newlast",
      email: "email@domain.com",
      password: "123456"
    }, {
      headers: {
        "X-XSRF-TOKEN": token //<- "X-XSRF-TOKEN" instead of "Authorization"
      }
    }
  ).then(function (response) {
```

confirmed that *"XSRF-TOKEN"* was created after "sanctum/csrf-cookie" request:

[image: XSRF-TOKEN created:]

Still getting "401 (Unauthorized)"
[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you confirm that you are sending correctly the bearer in the request?

Comment: add  this \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class to the kernel.php

Answer (score 0):

Helllo!

The ‘auth:sanctum’ middleware is used to protect endpoints against unauthenticated users.

So you should remove it from the register route as you are basically asking the user to authenticate themselves before registering an account.